# If $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective, is $g\circ f$ bijective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$. If $f$ is injective and
>   $g$ is surjective, is $g\circ f$ bijective?

I believe this is false, and have a counterexample. It was actually easier to draw than type, so here is a image representation.

[image: Proof]

Is this the right idea?

Comment: You have the right idea, but note that you need to send the second blue dot in $B$ to something in $C$ (this doesn't change anything). You can write down an even easier example if $|A|=1$, and $B=C$, with $|B|\geq 2$ and $g$ the identity map.

Comment: Why must the second blue dot go to $C$? If I only want to satisfy surjectivity, shouldn't this be enough?

Comment: It's part of the definition of a [function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) that every element in the domain must be sent somewhere in the codomain.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Comment: To answer the question in title: no, but the converse is true. A simple counterexample, $g:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R^+$ and $f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$, with $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are completely correct if you send the second blue dot in $B$ to some element in $C$.

Another possible example: let $f$ be the identity on some set $A$ with at least two elements, and let $g$ send all elements of $A$ to a single point $\{c\}$. Then $f \circ g$ is not injective, hence not bijective.